# Are questions about LINE on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

[LINE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINE_%28application%29) is a sort of Skype/Facebook utility, with PC/Mac/Android/iOS clients.

Most LINE questions do not depend on the operating system, so asking here sounds off-topic.

If LINE had a web interface, I would ask on Webapps (Facebook questions go there even if they are device-independent), but it has no web interface.

So, on-topic here, or better elsewhere, or better nowhere?

Comment: We've got quite a few Whatsapp questions too ([tag:whatsapp-messenger]), which as it's an almost identical app with almost identical functionality probably means whatever decision is made should count there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that as long as the question relates in some way to being Android usage, then I don't think this is a problem, and these questions are fine.

We already have many questions for cross-platform apps, particularly with messaging and social networking apps (even ones that also have a web interface). Have a look around some of these tags for examples [facebook](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook), [google-talk](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-talk), [whatsapp-messenger](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whatsapp-messenger), [gmail](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail).

Some of the answers to those questions will point out that some things are easier to do on the website than in the app, some are the other way around, and it's not always what you expect.